# Porting Java app to Go - any advice?

Tags: java, c, go

We want to rewrite kodingen.com backend with [Go](http://golang.org) which currently is
Java, running as daemon using [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html).

I have never touched any C in my life, am only experienced in Java so I
don't know if this is something that I should even start.

However, task is pretty simple

- read shell commands from mysql database
- queue and execute them in parallel
- save each shell output to the database

that's it. So these simple requirements gives me hope that I can start
using this wonderful language.

What would you advise? Is C still better ?

Comment: Hey are you the guys I heard pitching on TWIST? Anyway, just curious: what's wrong with Java? And why Go? Just curious.

Comment: Yes I'm the one who got beaten up :) But we made it to OAF in top5 in NYC right after that, Jason and Tyler were nice. Anyway, the reason is JVM eats 1,2GB of ram what would otherwise be 100k C daemon. There are many other reasons like random crashing due to apache exec commons etc. If you have an alternative solution please share here or u can mail me as well..

Comment: Also, why Go and not C ? Because, watching Go's tech talk, Rob Pike covered all the reasons why i have never touched C and said he removed them. and added all the things that I've wished were there in a system language, he said he added them.

Comment: Congrats on the NYC OAF. I hadn't heard that. 1.2GB is really high. It makes me think you're leaking memory somewhere. That's just for running shell commands?? Something is wrong if so. Is this for compiling code? Starting/stopping servers or EC2 instances or something?

Comment: i can't tell you much here but basically, it checks the the server load depending on that takes some actions. that part is fine. but executing shell commands from jvm is a nightmare... did u run any jsvc yourself? if so how was ur experience ? could u get it down to 50k 100k size?

Comment: I've only really used the Java service wrapper as it's a fairly convenient way of setting JVM options and restarting the server when it crashes. I've never used jsvc. I'm really surprised at the memory usage. Most memory usage should be transient in that a process is forked, it runs, it exits. I can't imagine why the controller process would get up to >1GB.

Comment: BTW I'm not arguing for or against Go. I don't really know a lot about Go but Java will have much wider library support and I *suspect* (but don't know for certain) that you have some issue that can be directly addressed. I don't htink you'll get down to a 100k footprint but you should get a lot less (by orders of magnitude) than 1.2GB. BTW feel free to contact me (follow the link on my profile).

Comment: @ecounysis yes it really is. do a search on google techtalk rob pike, and see it for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Go a lot and have made contributions to the project. However, I think you ought to consider a few things about Go before settling on it for sure.

- Go is still an unstable language. Its syntax, features, and packages are all subject to change. Make sure you're ready to keep up with this if you choose to use it.
- Go's garbage collection is still immature. Your memory usage should be better than 1.2 GB, but it probably won't get you near C levels.
- There's no core support for MySQL (or any other database). There are several unofficial MySQL package projects. The most recently updated ones are 
  [GoMySQL](http://github.com/Philio/GoMySQL) and [Go-MySQL-Client-Library](http://github.com/thoj/Go-MySQL-Client-Library). I don't know anything about how complete or stable they are.

As for queuing and executing in parallel, I think that's something Go will be able to do pretty well. You'll probably use the [exec](http://golang.org/pkg/exec/) package to execute and parallelize with goroutines.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Chickencha

At this point I have no plans to update my [1]: http://github.com/chbfiv/libmysqlgo "libmysqlgo" project. Contributions are welcome, but I'm too busy atm. I would recommend using more active mysql go projects.

Answer (score 1):

From the go langugage FAQ:

> The Go project was conceived to make
>   it easier to write the kind of servers
>   and other software Google uses
>   internally, but the implementation
>   isn't quite mature enough yet for
>   large-scale production use.

As I know, Go's garbage collector and scheduler is not ready yet.
And its compiler is not optimized enough, anyway, C compiler has been improved for 20 years.
If you want to use it in a production site, waiting for Go to be mature enough is better.

But that does not mean Go is not a good language to learn.
Actually, I'm happily using it to develop some useful utilities.

EDIT: Before you switch to another language, how about making some experiments with the forthcoming JDK 7. There are some improvements in the garbage collection.
You can check is the memory management better in your case.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, JDK7 looks good but what we need is a linux daemon not a program that runs in a closed environment (jvm) and interfaces with the system through some unknowns. To illustrate my point, imagine how absurd it'd be if apache was written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I think with the recent addition of panic/recover, Go is starting to become a viable option for website backends. I've been running a couple simple facebook apps using Go, but it's frustrating having the entire app go down for something like a map key error, or a null pointer exception. With panic/recover, it'll be possible to manage crashes.

About your requirements - it should be fine for mysql and shell commands. But be prepared to patch some libraries :)